# Css menu hovering background color issue

Tags: css

i have a very simple question for many, but complicated enough for me.
I have tried to fix this for the last hour with no luck.
I downloaded a css menu, and made all the modifications needed to me with no issue, but there's one thing that i'm having no luck trying to fix:
When hovering over "ccc" (for example), and going down to 1 for example (this happens to all other cells) the black background doesn't extend all the way to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be `padding-right` on `ul.cssmenu ul`. Removing that appears to fix it without unwanted side-effects, at least in Chrome on OS X. Question might be a better fit for Stack Overflow, too.